# Free node.js and mysql server

Tags: mysql, node.js, server, free

Well. I expended weeks trying to make Openshift server work. Then, I went to Heroku. Deployed my app in 10 minutes. But Heroku does not work with Mysql. I tried to make my app with Postgres. I REFUSE. Over a week trying to make that %S$% work, I'm too stressed. Went back to Mysql. In 10 minutes, it works. But... No Heroku (I don't want to put my credit card, it's a hobby thing). And... I tried to make in Openshift Redhat, but I cannot manage to put a Mysql DB...

Anyone knows any other free servers? I don't care about limitations, it will be a kinda small app... yeah, users playing online, but I can deal with small bandwidth, storage and etc... I can manage that. It's better than my other options: users trading .xml files in Facebook because we don't have a database.

Comment: Try [firebase](http://firebase.google.com/) (it's not exactly MySQL but it might serve your needs for a free database). PS: recommendations are likely to be closed as off topic

Comment: Get a cloud instance for 3$/month and don’t call free services you can’t handle shit

Comment: Maybe I need to hear that. At that point, I consider paying for a server if there's no other free. My app with mysql works in local, I'm too stressed to try anything else, 3$ month and fck this, too tired, too many weeks of time lost xDD Thanks. I'll take a break and... when I return, I'll consider this. I'll have to find servers... Or maybe with Heroku, it worked nice, and had MySql support if you entered a credit card.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain your own server, like [Debian](https://www.debian.org/distrib/)

It may be more trouble than it's worth because you will need a static IP address but perhaps you can experiment towards the launch and if you are serious about what you are doing then you can determine what to do after you know it works